# How to put Wordpress into a subfolder and redirect all specific traffic to it?

Tags: wordpress

I have a website in main folder with urls like:

domain.com/article/one etc.

Also i would like to install Wordpress into folder:

wordpress

But i would like urls to be NOT:

domain.com/wordpress/post/....

But:

domain.com/post/...

I would like to handle with .htaccess or index.php all requests to Wordpress so they are redirected to proper place in wordpress folder, so the main application will be intact.

How to make sure my basic app and wordpress will work together nicely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**change wp-options table value of home url and site url**

```
what you want like abc.com

and move your content to main directory where you want like public_html/
```